# django admin TinyMCE integration

Tags: django, django-admin, tinymce, textfield

This is weird: I have installed and configured django-tinymce, but it doesn't seem to work with django admin.

this works fine with Safari:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}, )},
    }
```

but i does *not* work within firefox.

Just adding the js does not work with either:

```
class Media:
    js = ['/media/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js']
```

I have tried various combinations of the path: with/without leading slash, with/without 'media' bit, even absolutely absolute http://localhost:8008/... Nothing worked for me.

Big fat **however**: using grappelli's own tinymce works in both firefox and safari (after adding safari into tinymce_config.js). Any idea what could go wrong?

Using Django 1.1, django-grappelli 2rc, django-tinymce 1.5, FF 3.5, Safari 4 on MacOS X 10.5

Comment: snipped requieres next imports: from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE, from django.db import models

Comment: Probably checking output of Firebug console will give you some hints. I had similar issue when TinyMCE language packs failed to load. Also, as mentioned in previous comment, make sure that you are importing `models` from `django.db`, not from your app.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest would be to use something like [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce)

Answer (score 1):

The rigth path of js is 'js/tiny_mec/tiny_mce.js', by the way if are you running with the dev server, are you serving your static files with a web server?

Comment: Yes, I set up the dev server to serve my static files. I discovered that grappelli might somehow collide with tiny_mce running in simple mode. Setting it to advanced mode helps, but I finally decided to switch to grappelli's custom tiny_mce.

Answer (score 1):

here is solution of this

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AddWYSIWYGEditor

it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    formfield_overrides = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}))

    class Meta:
        model = Article

class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ......
    form = ArticleForm

    class Admin:
        js = ('js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',
            'js/tiny_mce/textareas.js',
        )
```